# nginx returning 502 even though backup is live

Tags: nginx, node.js

Consider the following `nginx` config. I have two node js servers running on ports `8008` and `9008` respectively. I'm getting `502` errors in my `access.log` when I take down the server on `8008`. I've verified that the server on `9008` works by interchanging the ports and reloading the config. Why would I be seeing `502` errors?

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:8008 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=3s;
    server localhost:9008 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate ssl/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with `Connection: keep-alive`. A client with an active connection to the backend wouldn't know of it going down right away and thus try to make future requests over the same connection to the same backend server.